# Docker: Set value of ENV variable using RUN command?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm writing a Dockerfile to set up my customized WordPress environment. I'm starting with ubuntu:latest and would like to add some repositories dynamically, by setting an ENV variable to the codename of the current Ubuntu version. How can I do this, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start your container like this: `docker run -e VAR=value -e ANOTHER_VAR=another_value ...`. VAR and ANOTHER_VAR will be available in the container's environment.