# Use the result of RUN to set a variable

Tags: docker

I'd like to set a variable with `ENV` by using the result of running a command.

In bash would be like MY_VAR=`command\ but I can't get it working in Docker.

ENV MY_VAR=`command` will throw an error with the command and RUN export MY_VAR='command' won't work either.

I know [it's possible to pass these variable values from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891471/docker-set-value-of-env-variable-using-run-command) when invoking docker but I'm not invoking docker but a third party tool so I have to keep it all in the `Dockerfile`.

Edit:

This is what I'd like to export

> ENV IOJS_VERSION=`curl -s -L https://iojs.org/dist | sed -n -r 's/^.*(v([0-9].?)+).*$/\1/p' | sort -r | head -1`

Comment: can you show your Dockerfile and the RUN command in it?

Answer (score 0):

(The real solution is in the last paragraph. All the other things here just to answer your immediate question. Which is about a suboptimal solution of the underlying problem.)

A dirty trick is to use a file a storage, instead of the environment.
The relevant lines from Dockerfile for my use case (figure out the latest chromedriver version, and download it):

```
RUN wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(</tmp/CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION)/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN bash -c 'echo chromedriver version is $(</tmp/CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION)'
RUN bash -c 'wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(</tmp/CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION)/chromedriver_linux64.zip"'
```

Note the use of bash -c and the single tick ('). These are needed as I am using a bashism here. It might be that
    `cat /tmp/CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION`
would also work, without bash -c. I did not test this.

Also note that Docker cannot detect when the chromedriver version is actually changed, it will happily build the above lines from cache anytime. You can use the --no-cache option when building by hand, to overcome this and increase build time  lot, but I have no idea how to achieve this with docker hub.

Probably the right way to solve our use case is to set up a periodic build which monitor dependency versions, and commits a new version of Dockerfile when they are changed. It could in turn trigger a docker hub build.
This solution is also better in the sense that you can drive the testing of your shiny new docker image along the lines of your branching policy, so you won't suddenly have all kinds of breakages because new dependencies  break your system. This way you will still have the luxury of riding on the latest non-breaking version, and you get notifications when a breaking dependency rises.